# Suppose a and b belong to a commutative ring and ab is a zero-divisor. Show that either a or b is a zero-divisor.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose a and b belong to a commutative ring and ab is a zero-divisor. Show that either a or b is a zero-divisor.

My answer goes like this:
*If ab is a zero-divisor, then there exists a nonzero element c such that (ab)c = 0.

Assume b is not a zero divisor. Then bc is nonzero.  By using associativity, we can write (ab)c = 0 as a(bc) = 0.

This means that a is a zero-divisor (because bc is assumed to be nonzero).*
Is it really that easy?  Seems like there should be more to it.

Comment: Your answer is correct, if you find it easy look for harder, because there is always more difficult ones!

Comment: Yes, every part of math is so easy once you fully get there..

Comment: I think your proof glossed over an important logical fact, namely the use of the law of excluded middle , e.g. '$b$ is a zero divisor or $b$ is not a zero divisor'. In the former case the proof is done; in the latter case your proof continues. Also after "Assume $b$ is not a (non-zero) zero divisor" , you write "Then $bc$ is nonzero" , but this does not follow. It is possible that $b=0$.  True, if $b=0$ then $ab =0$ which contradicts $ab$ being a (non-zero) zero divisor. But you should state this. 
Also it is worth mentioning $bc$ is nonzero, otherwise $b$ would be a zero divisor.

Comment: You should not use "either-or" here. This phrase is often understood in the sense of an *exclusive or* (exactly one of both is true). But admittedly there does not seem to exist a commonly accepted interpretation of "either-or" in mathematics. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2130327.

Answer (score 1):

Let a and b belong to a commutative ring and ab be a zero-divisor.
Then there is a c ≠ 0 such that (ab)c = 0.
Observe that ab ≠ 0 implies that a ≠ 0 and b ≠ 0.
Suppose that a is not a zero divisor.
Then a(bc) = 0 implies that bc = 0 but this means that b is a zero-divisor.
Hence, either a or b is a zero-divisor.